# UnrecognizedPropertyException in FasterXML

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I read String `"{"name":"John","timestamp":"2020-08-14T11:47:52.297194Z"}"` when i convert it into POJO using fasterXML i get the below exception,

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "timestamp" (class com.job.model.Person), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties:  "name", "timeStamp"])
```

My POJO is,

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(keyspace = "keyspace", name = "testTable")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "timeStamp")
    //@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "UTC") // Tried with this no luck.
    private Instant timeStamp; 

}
```

I added the required dependency from the below url,

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8, and also

```
 <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           <version>2.11.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
            .addModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
            .addModule(new Jdk8Module())
            .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .build();
```

is registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json has `timestamp` while pojo has `timeStamp`. Either rename in pojo or use `@JsonProperty("timestamp")`

```java
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
private Instant timeStamp;
```

Comment: i will sure, but not allowing me to accept now. 10 min threshold.